# ParseException while applying Pivot function in Databricks

Tags: sql

I have a mailgroup table where each person can have max 20 email id & email ids are there in one column, column name is group_mailID, with comma separated value. I'm trying to split the mailids & create 20 columns to store the mail id. So I wrote following query in my `databricks 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)`

```
select Name,Address,Qualification,group_mailID,isnull([mailID1],'') as [mailID1],isnull([mailID2],'') as [mailID2],isnull([mailID3],'') as [mailID3],isnull([mailID4],'') as [mailID4],isnull([mailID5],'') as [mailID5],isnull([mailID6],'') as [mailID6],isnull([mailID7],'') as [mailID7],isnull([mailID8],'') as [mailID8],isnull([mailID9],'') as [mailID9],isnull([mailID10],'') as [mailID10],isnull([mailID11],'') as [mailID11],isnull([mailID12],'') as [mailID12],isnull([mailID13],'') as [mailID13],isnull([mailID14],'') as [mailID14],isnull([mailID15],'') as [mailID15],isnull([mailID16],'') as [mailID16],isnull([mailID17],'') as [mailID17],isnull([mailID18],'') as [mailID18],isnull([mailID19],'') as [mailID19],isnull([mailID20],'') as [mailID20] from
(SELECT RowID,Name,Address,Qualification, concat("mailID",  CAST(Row_Number() Over(Partition by RowID ORDER BY RowID) As STRING)) as col,group_mailID,explode(split(group_mailID, ',')) as mailID FROM mailgroup) as tbl Pivot(Max(mailID) for Col in ([mailID1],[mailID2],[mailID3],[mailID4],[mailID5],[mailID6],[mailID7],[mailID8],[mailID9],[mailID10],[mailID11],[mailID12],[mailID13],[mailID14],[mailID15],[mailID16],[mailID17],[mailID18],[mailID19],[mailID20])) as Pvt
```

But I'm getting parse Exception for outer select query with error message

```
ParseException: 
extraneous input '[' expecting {'APPLY', 'CALLED', 'CHANGES', 'CLONE', 'COLLECT', 'CONTAINS', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'COPY_OPTIONS', 'CREDENTIAL', 'CREDENTIALS', 'DEEP', 'DEFINER', 'DELTA', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'ENCRYPTION', 'EXPECT', 'FAIL', 'FILES', 'FORMAT_OPTIONS', 'HISTORY', 'INCREMENTAL', 'INPUT', 'INVOKER', 'LANGUAGE', 'LIVE', 'MATERIALIZED', 'MODIFIES', 'OPTIMIZE', 'PATTERN', 'READS', 'RESTORE', 'RETURN', 'RETURNS', 'SAMPLE', 'SCD TYPE 1', 'SCD TYPE 2', 'SECURITY', 'SEQUENCE', 'SHALLOW', 'SNAPSHOT', 'SPECIFIC', 'SQL', 'STORAGE', 'STREAMING', 'UPDATES', 'UP_TO_DATE', 'VIOLATION', 'ZORDER', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ALWAYS', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CATALOG', 'CATALOGS', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODE', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DAY', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DATEADD', 'DATEDIFF', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFAULT', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FN', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GENERATED', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GRANTS', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'HOUR', 'IDENTITY', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INCREMENT', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'ILIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MINUTE', 'MONTH', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENTILE_CONT', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PRECEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PROVIDER', 'PROVIDERS', 'PURGE', 'QUALIFY', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECIPIENT', 'RECIPIENTS', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'REMOVE', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPEATABLE', 'REPLACE', 'REPLICAS', 'RESET', 'RESPECT', 'RESTRICT', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SECOND', 'SCHEMA', 'SCHEMAS', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHARE', 'SHARES', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'SYNC', 'SYSTEM_TIME', 'SYSTEM_VERSION', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'TIMESTAMPADD', 'TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TRY_CAST', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VERSION', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', 'WITHIN', 'YEAR', 'ZONE', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 128)
```

I have added Backtick (``) at the beginning & end of square bracket based on some suggestion. After that I'm getting error message ParseException:  mismatched input 'as' expecting {, ';'}(line 2, pos 583)

My sample data looks like
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzrIZ.png)
My desired output looks like
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYqvu.png)
Can you please help me to reslove the issue?

Comment: Does that bracket "[" syntax work with any of your Databricks queries? Just tested it out and it gives the error even for a simple select.

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the first time I'm using databricks. I used bracket "[" based on some learning material

Comment: @Error_2646, I have added Backtick `(`)` at the beginning & end of square bracket  based on some suggestion. After that I'm getting error message `ParseException: 
mismatched input 'as' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 2, pos 583)`

Comment: Yeah, I've only seen that bracket syntax for escaping keywords in SQL Server and Access. Maybe more support it, but it isn't universal. Have you tried just removing them entirely? I don't see anything in your query that needs escaped.

Comment: Also, it's very helpful to provide sample data and associated create statements. That way people can easily reproduce your problem rather than just visually looking for syntax problems.

Comment: @Error_2646, I have added my sample data & desired output picture in my original post

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Added answer. In the future please don't post links to images. It makes things a lot easier if it's copy/pastable plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Idea is pretty much what you have but with corrected syntax.

```
with 
sample_data as (
SELECT sd.name,
       sd.country,
       sd.qualification,
       sd.email
    FROM VALUES ('John', 'US','MS','john@gmail.com,john@yahoo.com,john@hotmail.com'),
                ('Neil', 'US','MS','neil@altmail.com') AS sd(name, country, qualification, email)
),
explode_delimited_to_rows as (
select name,
       country,
       qualification,
       explode(split(email, ',')) as email,
       row_number() over ( partition by name order by 1) as row_num
  from sample_data
)
select * 
  from explode_delimited_to_rows 
 pivot (
    max(email) for row_num in (
      1 mail_1,
      2 mail_2,
      3 mail_3
    )
  )
```

| name | country | qualification | mail_1 | mail_2 | mail_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | US | MS | john@gmail.com | john@yahoo.com | john@hotmail.com |
| Neil | US | MS | neil@altmail.com | null | null |

Comment: Thanks, It works. I was trying to add the sample data & it was looking ugly, not in Tabular format. So I have added Text

Comment: @pythonlearner Yeah, the markdown can be finicky. There are online markdown table generators if you have it as csv or tsv. Honestly ChatGPT is very good at it too. Just plop your sample data in and ask it to convert it to a Stack Overflow markdown table.